# Is there any way that we can export(generate) editable PDFs in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pdf-form

I tried looking for different gem including wicked PDF, prawn, prawn forms, pdf-forms etc gems to enable a user to export editable PDFs but these gems weren't helpful. Can anyone guide me about any other gem or plugins that could be used for this purpose.

Comment: Isn't edit the pdf is the Adobe acrobat functionality? How does it matter from where the pdf have been generated?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching is AcroForm /  PDF Interactive Form. You can use PDFTron or Origami. I was using origami gems.

1. For PDFTron, you can check start from [here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/ruby/guides/features/forms/) and [here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/ruby/guides/features/forms/new-fields/).
2. For origami you can start from [here](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/blob/master/lib/origami/acroform.rb).

There are hardly any documentation for both, so you have to try a lot until it works like what you want.

I used origami because it is just a gem. Unlike pdftron, I don't have to install anything.